# Faster copying of images to change their PixelFormat

Tags: c#, performance, image

I have the following code below that creates a new `Bitmap` object the same as the original but to ensure that its `PixelFormat` is `24bppRgb`. Does anyone know if there is a faster way to do this:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
    }

    //...
```

Comment: The simple and most obvious optimization (which you may already have - hard to tell with just a snippet) is to skip out early if the image is *already* `24bppRgb`.  Other optimizations will probably involve pointer black magic and `Bitmap.LockBits`, and it may be best to ask for those types of optimizations on the main StackOverflow site.

Comment: @DanLyons I have already made that, and I would have done but I felt that this sort of question would be off topic over there.

Comment: Thanks for this question. The answers have saved my day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the alpha channel, you could use `Bitmap.Clone` :

```
public static Bitmap RemoveAlphaChannel(Bitmap bitmap) {
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    return bitmap.Clone(rect, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
}
```

Another way is to lock the bits without the alpha channel and then copy the memory to a new bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap RemoveAlphaChannel(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    Bitmap bitmapDest = (Bitmap)new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData dataDest = bitmapDest.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    NativeMethods.CopyMemory(dataDest.Scan0, data.Scan0, (uint)data.Stride * (uint)data.Height);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
    bitmapDest.UnlockBits(dataDest);
    return bitmapDest;
}

static class NativeMethods {

    const string KERNEL32 = "Kernel32.dll";

    [DllImport(KERNEL32)]
    public extern static void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint length);

}
```

Comment: First off the bitmap can be any format, whether that is `1bpp` or `32bpp` will your methods still work? Secondly I have tried the `.Clone` method before and it is 3x slower on my machine than what is provided in the question. If you're answering a question on performance at lest test your solutions.

Comment: A few other things why are you casting a `Bitmap` to a `Bitmap`? Can you add some spacing into the answer I can barely read whats going on because it is all clustered up. And as far as I know it is preferable to write the whole name not abbreviate i.e. `dataDest`.

Comment: I deleted my last comment as I realised the test I did was not fair, I gave the second method a fair test and it runs faster, thanks

Comment: As stated the method removes the alpha channel which is only present in a 32bpp image. So no it won't work for a 1bpp bitmap. Second, yes I tried the `.Clone` and find it 30% faster compared to `Graphics.DrawImage` when applyed to a screenshot from a webpage. But since you didn't bother to provide a sample or a context, yes there's a chance that it is slower for your specific usage.

Comment: I didn't 'bother' because the image can be pretty much anything for my usage and on my test images it was slower. And I know that's what you stated but it seems to work fine for using other formats too, although I need more testing to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be complete I created the following method based on the answer by Florent. The reason being is that this one should be a bit 'safer' and also allows for more extensibility.

The `try-finally`s are in place to ensure as much as possible that the `Bitmap`s do get unlocked.

```
public static Bitmap ChangePixelFormat(Bitmap bitmap, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, pixelFormat);
    try
    {
        Bitmap convertedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, pixelFormat);
        BitmapData convertedBitmapData = convertedBitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
        try
        {
            CopyMemory(convertedBitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Scan0, (uint)bitmapData.Stride * (uint)bitmapData.Height);
        }
        finally
        {
            convertedBitmap.UnlockBits(convertedBitmapData);
        }

        return convertedBitmap;
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
```